# Extract first and last name from email address. Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am really new to the SQL environment.
I am now facing a problem that I can't get solved.

I have a field email in which are the email addresses with the following format firstname.lastname@company.com

I now need a select that splits the email into first name, last name so like this.

```
marc.mueller@blablabla.com
```

to

```
Firstname Lastname 
marc      mueller
```

I was able to filter out the first name but the last name does not work.

```
select email,
       LEFT(email,CHARINDEX('.', email)-1) AS [New Firstname]
from data
```

Can someone pls point me in the right direction?
many greetings

Comment: As I know, dot is a filter and subdirectory separator. You can think that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we always have a single `.` separating first and last name, and will not appear anywhere else in the value, and also will only have a single `@` separating name and domain:

```
select left(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1), CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1) first_name
    , right(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1), len(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('.', email)) last_name
from tbl
```

Edit:

Here is a case statement to handle a missing `.` in the name:

```
select left(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1), CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1) first_name
    , case when email like '%.%@%' then right(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1), len(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('.', email)) else left(left(email, CHARINDEX('@', email) - 1), CHARINDEX('.', email) - 1) end last_name
from tbl
```

However, we have no way of knowing if it is the first or last name, so this will return the name in both columns.

Comment: I had already tried it in this way, but I get the error message that I have passed an invalid length parameter to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Yes and I think I have found the culprit... exactly one of the email addresses (from over 10000)has only lastname@company.com Can I somehow handle this in the query

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much you are the reason why the world still turns!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try substring function according to the index of "." and "@"

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(email,0,charindex('.',email)) as firstname,
SUBSTRING(email,charindex('.',email)+1,charindex('@',email)-charindex('.',email)-1) as lastname FROM data
```

Firstly, we split the email address according to the "." character and we got the firstname.
Secondly, we split the email address starting from the first "." character to the "@" character.

**Remember** substring syntax;
SUBSTRING(string, start, length)

So to find the length of the lastname sub string, we should subtract index of "@" from "."

Comment: I had already tried it in this way to, but I get the error message that I have passed an invalid length parameter to the SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @cybercore I don't know but I also tried this code using an online compiler, I got an output which you exactly want it. Your all records are the same type right? like "firstname.lastname@blabla.com". Are there any records missing '.' or '@' character?

Comment: I think I have found the culprit... exactly one of the email addresses (from over 10000)has only lastname@company.com Can I somehow handle this in the query

Comment: So, you can check the charindex result. If the charindex('.',email) result is 0, you can take all the left side as firstname or lastname depends on you.

Comment: Sorry I'm really just getting started with SQL, could you give me the example for this?

Answer (score 0):

And another alternative using parsename. CTEs are used to help "see" the logic flow but it can all be converted into a more compact form.

```
declare @x table (email varchar(200));
insert @x (email) values ('marc.mueller@blablabla.com'), ('lastname@company.com')
;

with cte_replace as (select replace(email, '@', '.') as p1 
    from @x
), 
cte_split as (select parsename(p1, 4) as p2, parsename(p1, 3) as p3 
    from cte_replace
)
select * from cte_split;
```

Notice how the logic handles a name without a period to separate first/last parts. An alternative to the REPLACE usage is to simple truncate from the @ sign.